# ResXMLTree_node header size 0x0 is too small in Android Menu

Tags: android, android-xml, android-menu

I'm currently setting up an app and stumbled upon some error which I don't understand.
I have a menu XML and provide here two icons. 
For the menu in the top right, I want to stick to the standard and use the three vertical dots which go by this name:

```
ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light
```

Unfortunately though, I get this error:
W/ResourceType(11504): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x0 is too small.

... and my R won't compile anymore.
However It works, for example with

```
ic_menu_info_details
```

or

```
ic_menu_search
```

Copying the icon itself in drawables didn't work either (?)
Does anyone have an explanation? The exisiting questions don't refer to this.

Here is the full code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_send"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Options"/>
```

The error comes, when I try to incorporate it like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_send"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Options"/>
```

Cleaning the code yields that R won't compile anymore.
I just would like to understand, maybe this icon doesn't exist? I googled it though.

Comment: Can you post your code ? specially when inflating the actionbar.

Comment: Hi, thnaks for the answer ... it really is just the menu XML. I attach it in the original question.

Comment: Strange... did you try Ctrl + spacebar at android:icon="@android:drawable/  If ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light gets resolved by eclipse (if you can see it suggested) then it probably has to do with the resource itself not being able to get compiled, hence R cannot get generated.

Comment: Thanks again for the effort.. 
But my application has set the minSdk for '14' (4.0).. so it can't be this either. I did use the ctr + space, to see it's not included in the list.                 I arrived at the conclusion that's it got to do with the face that I didn't set holo as my theme, I actually can't select any of the holo icons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking google i've found this:

[image]

It appears to be that this particular icon wasn't available pre Honeycomb (API 11). I am guessing that you may be getting this error because you're targetting the application to be supported pre-Honeycomb.

Can you try setting this on your manifest.xml:

```
<manifest>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks again for the effort.. 
But my application has set the minSdk for '14' (4.0).. so it can't be this either. I did use the ctr + space, to see it's not included in the list - maybe it's missing in the eclipse installation. Trying to find out more.